# Verilog output register not changing

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, cadence

I have to use combinational logic to write Verilog for a circuit schematic. However, my output registers, CLK1 and CLK2, do not change and are stuck at the initial values. What is causing this bug? Here is the code and output:

```
//Verilog HDL for "HW8", "ClockCircuit" "functional"

`resetall 
`celldefine
`delay_mode_path
`timescale 1ns / 10ps

module ClockCircuit (
    input  wire CLKin,
    output reg  CLK1,
    output reg  CLK2
);

    initial begin
        CLK1 = 0;
        CLK2 = 0;
    end
    
    // Intermediate signals
    wire inv_output;
    wire nor1_output;
    wire nor2_output;
    
    // Instantiate the inverter
    inv_1 inv (
        CLKin,
        inv_output
    );
    
    // Instantiate the first NOR gate
    nor_2 nor16 (
        CLKin,
        nor2_output,
        nor1_output
    );
    
    // Instantiate the second NOR gate
    nor_2 nor2 (
        nor1_output,
        inv_output,
        nor2_output
    );
    
    // Drive the outputs using procedural blocks
    always @(posedge CLKin) begin
        CLK1 <= nor1_output;
        CLK2 <= nor2_output;
    end
    
endmodule
`endcelldefine
```

[image]

The circuit I'm trying to create is here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What is causing this bug?

You have a simulation race condition.  All the signals in your code change at the same time, which means the output signals may not display all the actual transitions in your waveform viewer.

You need to change your Verilog code to use good coding style to avoid race conditions.  For example, your schematic shows combinational feedback paths: `CLK1` is fed back into logic driving `CLK2`, and vice versa.  This looks like you are attempting to model some type of latch.  It is improper to model latch behavior with gate-level modeling; you should use [behavioral modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog#Synthesizable_constructs) instead.